# How do I make an API call from clicking on a bar element in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to make an API call when clicking on a bar element. For example, look at this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-column/

See how the x axis has the 12 months? Let's say that when clicking on the bar for "April," I want to make an API call in order to get sales data for the month of April and display that on the graph. I can't find a way to do this, because this click function...

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      click: function (event) {
        //code goes here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... can only access items inside of the chart. I need to make an outside call to the database when clicking on a bar. Anything I can do? Thanks.

I tried this

```
document.querySelector('.rect.highcharts-point').addEventListener('click', e => {
  //code goes here
});
```

It didn't work at all which is confusing, because this method clearly works when referencing the chart as whole, but doesn't work for just a bar element as you can see it working for the entire chart in this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to have access to a specific point after clicking, you need to use `point.events.click()`  Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywopez1u/

Comment: No. I can do that. The problem is that  I can't access that event OUTSIDE of the highcharts object. Take a look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/ I need to be able to do this exactly, but with clicking on the bar element as opposed to the entire chart. The event for clicking on the bar element must be accessible outside of the chart, because I need to use information from the bar element outside of the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways how you can achieve that:

---

From the callback to the built-in point click() event:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click() {
            let point = this;
            getPoint(point)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

.

```
function getPoint(p) {
  console.log('From the callback: ', p)
}
```

From the div container:

```
document.querySelector('.chart-container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.point != undefined) {
    console.log('From the container: ', e.point)
  }
});
```

Looping through the rects:

```
 function getPointLoop(p) {
  p.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('From the loop:', e.target.point)
  })
}

let points = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('rect.highcharts-point'))

for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  getPointLoop(points[i])
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9bos6eu8/